# Angular.js | Sharing a ngModel

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, share

So, this is my HTML.

```
<input type="text" id="ghusername" ng-model="username" placeholder="Github username...">
    <span id="ghsubmitbtn" ng-click="getUsers()">Pull User Data</span>
```

This is my Controller A.

```
app.controller("homeController", ["$scope", "$http", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.getUsers = function () {
        $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + $scope.username)
          .success(function (data) {
              //some stuff
          })
```

And this is B (for posting sake). How do I get this username on the HTML ngModel, so that I can show it in another controller? ex:

```
app.controller("reposController", ["$scope", "$http", function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.getRepos = function () {
    $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + $scope.username + "/repos")
        .success(function (data) {
            // some stuff
        })
};
```

I've tried to user services, factories and even $rootScopes, but they just don't seem to work, any help? Btw, if I wasn't clear tell me and I will edit the post, Thank you.

---

**EDIT:** I ended up using $rootScope, I know it isn't the best idea but it was a minor thing. I'll keep all your answers for reference tho, as I'm sure they all work but I'm just too dumb to implement them..  Thank you.

Comment: The immediate answer is services - what have you tried and in what way doesn't it work?  Then we should be able to fix that.

Comment: Why is services not working?

Comment: @randomsock I don't know, that's the bad part. I have no clue, it seems easy enough on the web

Comment: @TheFabiocool could upload code with plunkr/fiddle..`service ` should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must to refernce $rootScope into your controllers:

```
app.controller("homeController", ["$scope", "$http","$rootScope", function ($scope, $http, $rootScope) ...
```

and after that just access rootscope variables:

controller1: `$rootScope.someValue = "some value";`
Controller2: `$scope.controllerScopeValue = $rootScope.someValue`;

Comment: This is a nice simple solution, but I can't help getting the feeling it's like saying "make it global then you can access it from anywhere"

Comment: The nice thing about this is once you've added it to the `$rootScope` it's then automatically available through your other controller's own `$scope` (because all scopes prototypically inherit from root).  So in controller2, you should just be able to say `$scope.someValue`.

Comment: randomsock - you are right. The action in controller2 is redundant

Comment: @OlegYudovich I $rootScope wasn't working like so: $rootScope.name = $scope.username;  I ended up kinda cheating and using  $rootScope.name = document.getElementById("ghusername").value;

Answer (score 0):

Use `service`

```
app.service('name', [function(){}])
```

Then add `'name'` to both the `controllers` like

```
app.controller("reposController", ["$scope", "$http", 'name', function ($scope, $http, name) {

$scope.name = name;
```

Then you can access it like

```
name.username
```

and in html

```
<input type="text" id="ghusername" ng-model="name.username" placeholder="Github username...">
```

Answer (score 0):

With some assumptions about your data model, this should work.

It creates a `shared` singleton object.  One controller adds the user (or whatever data) as an attribute of that.  Then other controllers, or indeed the same controller if it is reloaded, can then access the same data on `shared`.

Note here that a `service` just returns a singleton of anything, it doesn't need code or methods.  In this case, it's easier to use a `value` instead which is shorthand for `function() { return {}; }` and works just as well.

Remember to inject `shared` wherever it is needed.

```
app.controller("homeController", ["$scope", "$http", "shared", function ($scope, $http, shared) {
    $scope.getUsers = function () {
        $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + $scope.username)
          .success(function (data) {
              shared.user = data.user; // or wherever it comes from
              //some stuff
          })

app.controller("reposController", ["$scope", "$http", "shared", function ($scope, $http, shared) {
$scope.getRepos = function () {
    $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + shared.user.name + "/repos")
        .success(function (data) {
            // some stuff
        })
};

app.value('shared', {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

http://jsfiddle.net/devkickstart/nevyhdn0/2/

Using a factory you can share the data between controller like so...

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div data-ng-controller="reposCtrl">
        <input type="text" id="ghusername" ng-model="username" placeholder="Github username..." ng-init="getRepos()" />
        {{data}}
    </div>
    <div data-ng-controller="homeCtrl"> <span id="ghsubmitbtn" ng-click="getUsers()">Pull User Data</span>
    {{otherData}}
    </div>
</div>

angular.module("myApp", [])
.factory("dataFact", ["$rootScope", function ($rootScope) {
    var myData = "value from factory";
    return {
        getData: function () {
            return myData;
        },
        setData: function (newVal) {
            this.myData = newVal;
        }
    }
}]).controller("homeCtrl", ["$scope", "dataFact", function ($scope, dataFact) {
    $scope.getUsers = function () {
        $scope.otherData = dataFact.getData();
    }
}]).controller("reposCtrl", ["$scope", "dataFact", function ($scope, dataFact) {
    $scope.getRepos = function () {
        $scope.username = dataFact.getData();
    }
}]);
```